# How to map the native meory usage statistics for heap dump to JVM memory map diagram

Tags: java, jvm, memory-mapping

I have the following info with me:

---

NATIVE MEMORY USAGE

---

Type, Memory Used (bytes), Object Count

---

ByteCode, 3015540, 28000
Const Pool, 1978128, 3412
UTF8 Strings, 6089367, 89281
UTF16 Strings, 1934, 8
Offscreen Images, 0, 0
Static Data, 52624, 1393
Bitmaps, 0, 0
CWT, 288172, 579
VTables, 468764, 3629
CVTables, 469712, 3629
ITables, 273504, 2814
Class Meta, 59484, 2835
GCTables, 64940, 2052
GCStaticTables, 31864, 1372
Method Blocks, 1575440, 3392 (num methods : 32821)
Field Blocks, 345888, 2035 (num fields : 17294)
VM Chunk Data TYPE_MMPOINTER, 0, 0
VM Chunk Data TYPE_OBJECTREF, 12292, 1
VM Chunk Data TYPE_PURGEPROCPTR, 0, 0
VM Chunk Data TYPE_FORWARDREF, 0, 0
VM Chunk Data TYPE_MONITORCACHE, 6422724, 49
VM Chunk Data TYPE_PROFTHREADINFO, 0, 0
VM Chunk Data TYPE_CODEFIXUP, 0, 0
VM Chunk Data TYPE_WIDGET, 8196, 1
VM Chunk Data TYPE_MEMTRACKER, 0, 0
VM Chunk Data TYPE_GRAPHICSCONTEXT, 0, 0
VM Hashes, 17432, 2
Generated Code, 0, 0
JAR File Name Tables, 4424, 7
JAR File Tables, 6720, 7
Unspecified, 3201427, 9318

---

But I would like to know how to map this to the JVM memory map, for understanding this more clearly.

I searched through the internet, but was unable to find a proper map diagram which could resemble everything in this.

All pointers are welcome.

Comment: What are you trying to show? What is the aim of this?  This only tells you about the internals of the JVM, not the application running in the JVM. Are you trying to tune a custom JVM?

Comment: Actually I just want to get a feel of the JVM and its internals. How things are arranged and where is it put in the memory. For eg. the difference in Const Pool and UTF8 Strings..

Comment: You could graph the table in excel if you like.

Comment: I am not interested in the graphs and numbers. I am actually interested in the areas inside JVM.

Comment: Usually people use tools like VisualVM.  The rest rarely makes a difference.